# Messaging menu indicator does not work for Thunderbird

Tags: 11.10, indicator, thunderbird, messaging-menu

I updated to Oneiric recently and now the messaging menu is not working properly for Thunderbird anymore. When I get a new e-mail, the envelope does not change at all (No visible notification). Additionally no bubble appears telling me about the new message. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). I will flag this question for closing.

Comment: On a second thought, better search on Launchpad first. This got te be already reported (yes, I'm seeing this too).

Comment: Same issues here: the envelope does not turn blue when new mail has arrived and the message count is not displayed in the message menu despite I have no extension previously installed in 11.04.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to *disable* any extension you had working in 11.04 to get this functionality.  According to the details of the one I had, it is now integrated into the Ubuntu Oneiric version of Thunderbird, and they recommend disabling the original add-on.  After doing so, my indicator pop-up is working.  (However, I still don't get an unread message counter on the Thunderbird icon in the Unity launcher...)